# Existence of an entire function $f.$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

If $\{z_n\}$ is a sequence of distinct complex numbers in unit circle such that $z_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, there exist an entire function $f$ such that $f(z_n)=z_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(5)=0$. (T/F)

My work: Consider $g(z)=f(z)-z$, clearly $g(z_n)=0$. Thus by identity and uniqueness theorem $g(z)=0 $ for all $z$ in the unit circle, i.e $f(z)=z$, so $f(5)=5$, and the above statement is false.

CHECK the logic.

Comment: Capitals are considered as rude and offensive

Comment: How can the $z_n$'s be on the unit circle while $z_n \to 0$?

Comment: If $f(z)=z$ for all $z$ in unit circle, how do you conclude $f(5)=5$?? $5$ does not belong to unit circle.

Comment: @cello, yes ur point is correct, so is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't get confused by what they are saying. They are pretending not to understand that what you call circle should be unit disc. Your proof if correct. $g(z)$ is entire as the sum of two entire functions and the identity principle gives you that $g(z)$ is identically zero.

Comment: @orole rather, it is a **rhetorical question**, intended to get the OP fix the statement.

Comment: @orole, thanks a lot, but how can I put value $5$ where my function on unit disk. Please help

Comment: @1256 Your function is said to be entire. You can evaluate it at any number. Even if we change the problem by only saying that $f$ is analytic at $0$ and defined in a neighborhood of $0$ we can still do it. In this case we need to add a little more to the explanation. Explanation for that new problem: You have proved that $z$ is an analytic continuation of $f$ to the whole plane. Since the whole plane is simply connected, then the analytic continuation is unique. Therefore $z|_{z=5}$ is the value of (the analytic continuation of ) $f$ at $z=5$.

Comment: @orole, sorry, I got it.